# How I can @CachePut for collection in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, ehcache

For caching I am using `Ehcache3` as provider. Let's say I have this methods:

```java
@Transactional
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "findAllPosts")
public Page<Post> getAllPosts(Pageable pageable) {
    return postRepository.findAll(pageable);
}

@Transactional
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "findPostById")
public Post findById(Long id) {
    return postRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(exceptionHelper.getEntityNotFoundException(id, Post.class));
}

@Transactional
@CachePut(cacheNames = "findPostById", key = "#result.id")
public Post update(Long postId, Post postToUpdate) {
    Post post = postRepository.getOne(postId);
    post.setTitle(postToUpdate.getTitle());
    post.setContent(postToUpdate.getContent());
    post.setUpdated(LocalDateTime.now());
    return post;
}
```

I want to of course cache this methods. It works, but `@CachePut` affect only `findPostById` and does not affect `findAllPosts` even if I add `findAllPosts` to cacheNames. When I am updating Post, it is visible for single post (by id) and not for `getAllPosts` (cache is not updated for this method). What can I do to update not only single entity but whole collection? Is there something like `@CollectionCache`?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not because you use 'key' in your @CachePut method, but don't use a key in your findAllPosts() and findPostById() ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this would be to evict the cache for the list whenever a single element gets updated.

You would have to autowire the cacheManager, access the cache from there and evict what youn need manually in the update method.

Sample code:

```
@Autowired 
private CacheManager cacheManager;

@Transactional
@CachePut(cacheNames = "findPostById", key = "#result.id")
public Post update(Long postId, Post postToUpdate) {

    Cache allPostsCache = cacheManager.getCache("cacheName").evict("cacheKey");

    Post post = postRepository.getOne(postId);
    post.setTitle(postToUpdate.getTitle());
    post.setContent(postToUpdate.getContent());
    post.setUpdated(LocalDateTime.now());
    return post;
}
```

Ofcourse you need to replace "cacheName" and "cacheKey" with your values.